Why does my script to copy folders fail?
I need to make a local copy of everything within the iCloud Drive folder. Here is what I have so far:
#!/bin/bash

#make archive folder is desired location
mkdir /Users/username/iCloud\ Drive\ Archive

#delay
sleep 2

#copy files and folder from iCloud Drive to previously created archive location
cp –R /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs 
/Users/username/iCloud\ Drive\ Archive

The archive folder is creating properly, but the copy portion isn't executing. Any advice would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

The dash that you have used for 'cp –R' looks to be an en dash ('–') and not a regular hyphen or minus ('-').

When I do it (with -Rv): cp: –Rv: No such file or directory zsh: permission denied: /Users/gilby/iCloud Drive Archive

I don't believe that the cp "isn't executing". Maybe it does not have the desired effect, but cp should be started. Proof your point by running the script with set -x and post the output!

Also make sure that you have write permission for the destination directory.

@pdd had the answer: The dash that you have used for cp –R is an en dash (–) and not a regular hyphen or minus (-)

If this was really the reason, your original command should have produced an error message---

I'm glad you could make the script work. Could you mark your answer as accepted? You will not only collect the reward but also help others with a similar issue. Thank you in advance.
